# How do I create a range out of the cells above a table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have formulas in the row right above the header row of my table/range. **I want to copy the formula values and paste them to the last (new) row of the table/range.** I know how to make the code work except for the reference to the row with the formulas.

This is code that I tried to reference the cell two rows above the first cell in my table (that I set/defined as the range).

```
Set rangeTopLeft = rangeActive.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-2)
```

I get a 1004 error.

I go on to create a range by resizing `rangeTopLeft` and perform the other steps to copy and paste values from the formulas to the new row.

I don't get an error if I use `.Offset(-1)`, but that only gets me to the first column cell in my header row. I'm guessing, offset cannot go beyond the boundaries of the range.

```vb
'Paste Last Week's Formula Values to New Rows

Sub PasteValues()

Dim rangeList As Range
Dim rangeActive As Range
Dim rangeToCopy As Range
Dim lastRow As Range
Dim rangeName As String

Dim rowNumber As Integer
Dim dataBeginColumn As Integer
Dim actionColumn As Integer
Dim actionType As String

Dim nameColumn As Integer
Dim dataColumnFirst As Integer
Dim dataColumnLast As Integer

Dim response1 As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim response2 As VbMsgBoxResult

Set rangeList = Range("tTablesDetails").ListObject.DataBodyRange

nameColumn = 1
actionColumn = 7
actionType = "Append"

'Requires user to click "Yes" twice before pasting values
response1 = MsgBox("Do you want to past last week's formula values to tables of this Workbook?", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
If response1 = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
response2 = MsgBox("Are you sure? This action cannot be undone.", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
        
If response2 = vbNo Then Exit Sub
      
For rowNumber = 1 To rangeList.Rows.Count
        
    If rangeList.ListObject.DataBodyRange(rowNumber, actionColumn).Value = actionType Then
        
        'get table name from row whose action column equals actiontype
        rangeName = rangeList.ListObject.DataBodyRange(rowNumber, nameColumn).Text
            
        Set rangeActive = Range(rangeName)
            
        Set rangeTopLeft = rangeActive.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-2)
                
        Set rangeToCopy = rangeTopLeft.Resize(1, rangeActive.Columns.Count)
            
        Set lastRow = rangeActive.Offset(rangeActive.Rows.Count).Resize(1, rangeActive.Columns.Count)
            
        lastRow = rangeToCopy.Value
                   
    End If
     
Next
     
MsgBox ("Finished Copying Values to New Rows")
    
End Sub
```

Update: I solved this with the following snippet.

`tableList` is a Range object made from a table in the workbook listing details of the various tables in the workbook. The Range object does not require specifying the sheet on which a **table** is located.

```vb
For rowNumber = 1 To tableList.Rows.Count
    If tableList.Item(rowNumber, actionColumn).Value = actionType Then
        tableName = tableList.Item(rowNumber, nameColumn).Value
        Set activeTable = Range(tableName)
        With activeTable
            .Rows(.Rows.Count + 1).Value = activeTable.Rows(-1).Value
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How is `rangeActive` assigned, and where is the table?

Comment: I don't think we have the full picture, but I'd guess that you would want `rangeActive.Rows(1).Offset(-2)` ... but we still need to know about `rangeActive`.

Comment: see code above that I added. the rangeActive assignment changes as the code loops the names of tables on various sheets of the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in properties of a `ListObject`, specifically the [`HeaderRowRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.headerrowrange).

And no need to resize and then copy/paste values, you can simply do a value transfer from the row above the `HeaderRowRange` to a newly added `ListRow`.

Perhaps something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Set myTable = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim formulaRange As Range
    Set formulaRange = myTable.HeaderRowRange.Offset(-1)

    myTable.ListRows.Add.Range.Value = formulaRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Code added above

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SO()
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    With lst.DataBodyRange
        .Rows(.Rows.Count + 1).Value = .Rows(1).Offset(-2).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen I have corrected code once again - now everything works as expected: values from formulas are written to the end of table. 

Comment: thank you. will this work if I am looping through different table names therefor working with tables on different sheets as I loop? ...I have a number of tables in the workbook on different sheets that I'm repeating this process on.

Comment: @Nik Yes, this will work on any table as far as formulas are always above table's header. You just need to adapt my code to use correct sheet (and table name, if it's required).

Comment: So, I will need to define the sheet for each table as I loop through them? I can add a column to my "table name lookup list" that contains the sheet name it's on. Was hoping to get around this. I thought that using Range() you didn't have to tell VBA where the table is located....

Comment: @Nik *I will need to define the sheet for each table as I loop through them?* Yes, since every `ListObject` belongs to `Worksheet`. *I can add a column to my...* You can get list of tables' names from anything you want (including hard-coding).  *I thought that using Range() you didn't have to tell VBA where the table is located* And do you imagine how to do it? `ListObjects` is for very this thing - locating tables. You could, of course, store locations of tables, but it's not worth it - use `ListObjects` instead.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I did get this to work using the Range object which does not care about which sheet the table is located in the workbook. Revised snippet of code above in original post.